# How do I add typekit fonts to a D8 theme?

Tags: theming, 8

Having looked over the existing D8 documentation on adding JS to the `<head>` of a page, I'm still not sure how to go about it?

What is the correct way to achieve this on every page for my theme:

```
<script src="//use.typekit.net/abc0abc.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

Regarding inline JS, from the [latest D8 documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195):

> In the case of front-end/styling (e.g. hosted font services), the JS
>   belongs in the theme. Put the JS directly in your html.html.twig file.
>   In the case of fonts, this will also allow you to put it right in the
>   place that gives you the best (and fastest) end user experience,
>   because it allows you to prevent a FOUT (Flash Of Unstyled Text) while
>   the font is still loading (fonts loaded through JS must be listed in
>   the HTML  before the CSS)!

So, I guess the inline JS goes directly into `html.html.twig`, but what about the external file?

I have this in my theme files, but it's not adding the external file to any pages:

mytheme.info.yml

```
libraries:
  - mytheme/typekit
```

mytheme.libraries.yml

```
typekit:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    //use.typekit.net/abc1abc.js: { type: external }
```

Comment: Here is a good documentation about how to add JS and CSS in Drupal 8 http://www.appnovation.com/blog/how-add-js-and-css-assets-drupal-8-theme

Comment: I think the docs are suggesting to put both lines in your html.html.twig. As far as I know it's not possible to add inline JS via the libraries API. If it's loaded on every page I'm not sure it's worth the effort/obscurity to convert it to a render array like in @MrD's answer, or to even use the libraries API. Just paste it in and be done with it, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For put the library to the header you must user `header: true`, then:

mytheme.info.yml

```
libraries:
  - mytheme/typekit
```

mytheme.libraries.yml:

```
typekit:
  version: 1.x
  header: true
  js:
    //use.typekit.net/abc1abc.js: { every_page: true }
    js/custom.js: { every_page: true }
```

js/custom.js:

```
try { 
  Typekit.load(); 
} 
catch(e) { 
}
```